# Can I get help on how to join my table using below tags?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to display posts from `main_posts` to the users to whom they have followed. I was able to do so, but I have no idea how to display username from `User` table who have posted in `main_posts`. I think I have to use join but I don't know how. Sorry for my bad English.

```
SELECT id, content from main_posts where id in (
    SELECT user_to_id from main_followings
    where user_by_id = 1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` to the user table.

Comment: If you show us the schemas for the 2 tables involved you will get a very quick answer. Post the output from a `show create table main_posts` and `show create table main_following`

Comment: how can I upload my image here?

Comment: Hi, thats not the Schema, we need the 2 schemas

Comment: https://ibb.co/fNvhMwj okay this is @RiggsFolly